# .htaccess Rewrite Images to Different Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working with Craft CMS locally on my Mac which works, but the path is `localhost/project/public` which is not desirable. I created a RewriteRule that allows me to use `localhost/project` which works, but now none of the images, styles, and other assets no longer work.

I'm thinking I need to create a RewriteRule to redirect all my assets to another path. Here is what I ended up with.

```
RewriteEngine On

# hide public in the url
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]

# my attempt to fixing all the broken assets
RewriteRule ^/assets/logos/(.*)$ public/assets/logos/$1
```

Any ideas on why my RewriteRule is not working?

**EDIT**
This has been falsely marked as a duplicate. The duplicate suggests I change the markup to add forward slashed to point to root. No where did I suggest or want to change my markup. I am looking to make this work via .htaccess.

Comment: Hm, I tried what you guys are saying is a duplicate and it does not work... maybe it's not a duplicate?